# Masking in AS3 from below, keeping mask visible?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

Okay, I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, but maybe someone can think of a neat combo of effects that can make this happen:

I want a [large, complex] movieclip to act as a mask to another movieclip above it, AND not disappear itself.

The point is to let a user drag various objects onto a character, and have them appear "on the skin", so only visible where the character movieclip is.
Previously I've done this by creating a mask that is the same shape as the character, but this time the character MC is SO complex and dynamic that it's just not feasible.

Is there an easy way to dynamically duplicate the complex MC and make that the mask?  Is there a way to make the Erase filter erase using negative space instead of content?  Ideas?

Edit:

At first the answer below wouldn't work due to high pixellation and scaling issues, but I was able to resolve these by drawing the parent instead, allowing smoothing as suggested, and tinkering lots.

```
    // remove old bitmap to replace with new one as needed
    if(grl.tempContainer.numChildren >= 1){
        grl.tempContainer.removeChildAt(0);
    }
    // make hair disappear so only visible skin is part of mask
    grl.hair.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    grl.hair.blendMode = 'erase';
    grl.hair2.alpha = 0;
    grl.ponytail.alpha = 0;
    grl.body.braids.alpha = 0;
    grl.filters = [];
    grl.body.filters = [];

    // create bitmap copy of the character
    var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(400, 600, true, 0);
    bmd.draw(this.parent);
    var clone:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
    clone.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    clone.smoothing = true;
    grl.tempContainer.addChild(clone);
    // undo the scaling effects that were on girl to revert to parent scaling/position
    clone.scaleX = 1/grl.scaleX;
    clone.scaleY = 1/grl.scaleY;
    clone.x = -(clone.width)/2;
    clone.y = -(75/(grl.scaleY));

    grl.draggieContainer5.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    grl.draggieContainer5.mask = clone;

    // reset character to look normal again
    grl.hair.blendMode = 'normal';
    grl.hair2.alpha = 1;
    grl.ponytail.alpha = 1;
    grl.body.braids.alpha = 1;
    grl.filters = filterHolder.filters;
    grl.body.filters = filterHolder.filters;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've already figured this out, but I think you would have to create a 2nd character object to use for the mask.

> Is there an easy way to dynamically duplicate the complex MC and make
>   that the mask?

If your mc is static, you could draw it to a bitmap first and use that as the mask.

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;

//Create Character
var character:Character = new Character();
character.x = 100;
character.y = 50;
stage.addChild(character);

//Clone it
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(character.width, character.height, false, 0);
bmd.draw(character);
var clone:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
clone.x = character.x;
clone.y = character.y;
stage.addChild(clone);

//Tattoo is masked to the clone
var tattoo:Tattoo = new Tattoo();
stage.addChild(tattoo);
tattoo.mask = clone;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mousemove);
function mousemove(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    tattoo.x = mouseX;
    tattoo.y = mouseY;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since you're character most likely has transparent areas, you actually need to do a bit more work.
In order to give your bitmap transparency, you need to set the third param to true, and the 4th param to 0.

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(grl.body.width, grl.body.height, true, 0);
```

In your character body, the registration point is in the center, but the draw function draws from the top-left. In order to draw correctly, you need to apply a matrix to the draw function:

```
//Apply Matrix so the entire image gets drawn
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.translate(grl.body.width/2, grl.body.height/2);
bmd.draw(grl.body, matrix);

//Draw the clone image
var clone:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
```

Now your bitmap should display correctly, but it will be positioned with its top-left aligned with the center of the original image. You need to move it back so it is positioned the same as before.

```
var t:Transform = new Transform(clone);
matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.translate(grl.body.x-grl.body.width/2, grl.body.y-grl.body.height/2);
t.matrix = matrix;
clone.scaleX = grl.body.scaleX;
clone.scaleY = grl.body.scaleY;
```

Now there are 2 things you need to do in order for the mask to correctly blend with the alpha channels. You must set the blend mode to ALPHA and you must set cacheAsBitmap to true for both the displayobject and the mask object.

```
clone.cacheAsBitmap = true;
clone.blendMode = BlendMode.ALPHA;
grl.addChild(clone);

grl.draggieContainer.cacheAsBitmap = true;
grl.draggieContainer.mask = clone;
```

Comment: Okay, this definitely seems to be going to right direction =)
I'm trying to integrate it into my code.  I'm not using the first section since I already have the MC.  I'm only using the mask line from the last section since I already have my "draggieContainer".
But I'm having all sorts of trouble with the middle.. When dragging new items, the first time nothing happens.  The subsequent rounds a giant, opaque rectangle forms which has my character, a white background, and the draggie object.  I think this can work.. I just have to iron out these kinks..

Comment: My character doesn't have the registration point on the top left which is hurting my brain haha...

Comment: The third parameter in the BitmapData constructor is a Boolean for transparency. You can change that to true to remove the white background.

Comment: As for the other issues, you'll have to update your question to include some code

Comment: I've added my latest code.  Despite setting it to "true", I'm still getting a giant white-containing rectangle O.o
And there's definitely registration issues because now the clone appears at the right spot, but it cuts off the left and top halves of the character... and the mask doesn't seem to be working at all.  Nothing is acting like a mask =(

Comment: @ola.rogula Because of the transparency and the centered anchor point, this turned out to be much more challenging than I originally thought. But I've updated my answer with a solution that should work for your case. Give it a try.

Comment: Aw, this is so close.. I'm having layers upon layers of scaling/positioning issues, which I half ironed out.  But the biggest problem is the quality is terrible.  I tried drawWithQuality but it wasn't better.  The thing is the character is scaled up, but the copy is drawn from the original size, so the pixellation is really visible.  Even as a mask, it clips, more like gnaws, the item edges off hahaha.  I might have to try duplicating the mc fully, but I imagine that will just eat resources.  I can cacheasbitmap I guess... :/

Comment: ...your new code edits did all solve the aforementioned problems though, thank you =)

Comment: ...oh crap, it doesn't sound like it's possible to duplicate a heavily user edited movieclip >_<

Comment: Ypu can turn on bitmap smoothing which should reduce the pixelation (but might look blurry instead) `var clone:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd, "auto", true);` The best option though is probably to draw the bitmap before you scale the original.

Comment: No wait.. there's an easier way!  I can draw the parent!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92548/discussion-between-ola-rogula-and-karmacon).